# How to compare list values with dictionary keys and make a new dictionary of it using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, generator

I have a list like this:

```
lis = ['Date', 'Product', 'Price']
```

I want to compare it with:

```
dict = {'Date' : '2013-05-01', 'Salary' : '$5000', 'Product' : 'Toys', 'Price' : '$10', 'Salesman' : 'Smith'}
```

I want to compare each item of list with keys of dictionary and make a new dictionary.
What I have tried is:

```
n = {}
for k,v in dict.items():
    for i in lis:
        if i==k:
            n[k] = v
```

Output:

```
n = {'Date' : '2013-05-01', 'Product' : 'Toys', 'Price' : '$10'}
```

This works but I want to do it through generators - can someone help me do that?

Comment: Don't call your `dict` `dict` it will shadow the `dict` in Python, use `d` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Treat `lis` as a set instead, so you can use [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) and an intersection:

```
# python 2.7:
n = {k: d[k] for k in d.viewkeys() & set(lis)}

# python 3:
n = {k: d[k] for k in d.keys() & set(lis)}
```

Or you could use a simple dict comprehension with a `in` test against `d`:

```
# python 2.6 or older:
n = dict((k, d[k]) for k in lis if k in d)

# python 2.7 and up:
n = {k: d[k] for k in lis if k in d}
```

This presumes that not all values in `lis` are going to be in `d`; the `if k in d` test can be dropped if they are always going to be present.

For your specific case, the second form is quite a lot faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("{k: d[k] for k in d.viewkeys() & s}", 'from __main__ import d, lis; s=set(lis)')
2.156520128250122
>>> timeit("{k: d[k] for k in lis if k in d}", 'from __main__ import d, lis')
0.9401540756225586
```

Comment: Wouldn't `{k: d[k] for k in list if k in d}` be more efficient than `{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in lis}`? That way the `in` check is always done against the dict (amortized O(1)) instead of the list (O(n))

Comment: Great solution - quick note though, this does not work during debugging.  If you're pulling your hair out like I just did, know that this solution is correct in 3.6.  [Heres](https://github.com/inducer/pudb/issues/103) a ticket explaining what's going on with dict comprehension and debugging.

Comment: @JamieMarshall that’s because you can’t create new closures in an existing local scope. You’d have to set globals first or wrap the comprehension in a new scope (like a lambda).

Answer (score 1):

```
filtered_dict = dict((k, original_dict[k]) for k in lis if k in original_dict)
```

Or if you have 2.7+:

```
filtered_dict = {k: original_dict[k] for k in lis if k in original_dict}
```

If you want to use a generator:

```
item_generator = ((k, original_dict[k]) for k in lis if k in original_dict)
```

The generator will yield `(key, value)` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6

```
dict_keys_list = list(dict.keys())
dict_keys_list.sort()
for key in dict_keys_list:
     if key in lis:
          print("Key is present")
```

Another approach where you want to compare a list of keys to be equal to the dictionary keys.

```
person = { 'name' : 'Don', 'nickname' : 'John', 'age' : 45, 'salary' : 50000, 'place' : 'Monaco, Europe' }
compare_list = ['nickname', 'place', 'name', 'salary', 'age']
person_keys_list = list(person.keys())
person_keys_list.sort()
compare_list.sort()
person_keys_list == compare_list # Gives you True
```