# Compare list of lists with a dictionary and get output as list of list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of list of strings and a dictionary:

```
docsp = [['how', 'can', 'I', 'change', 'this', 'car'], ['I', 'can', 'delete', 'this', 'module']]

ent = {'change' : 'action', 'car' : 'item', 'delete' : 'action'}
```

I want to compare the dictionary with the list of lists and tag the list elements with dictionary key value pairs to a new list of tuples like below.

```
newlist = [[('how', 'O'), ('can', 'O'), ('I', 'O'), ('change', 'action'), ('this', 'O'), ('car', 'item')], [('I', 'O'), ('can', 'O'), ('delete', 'action'), ('this', 'O'), ('module', 'O')]]
```

I tried the following code:

```
n = []
for k,v in ent.items():
    for i in docsp:
        for j in i:
            if j==k:
                n.append((j,v))
            n.append((j, 'O'))
n
```

and getting the below output:

```
[('how', 'O'),
 ('can', 'O'),
 ('I', 'O'),
 ('change', 'action'),
 ('change', 'O'),
 ('this', 'O'),
 ('car', 'O'),
 ('I', 'O'),
 ('can', 'O'),
 ('delete', 'O'),
 ('this', 'O'),
 ('module', 'O'),
 ('how', 'O'),
 ('can', 'O'),
 ('I', 'O'),
 ('change', 'O'),
 ('this', 'O'),
 ('car', 'item'),
 ('car', 'O'),
 ('I', 'O'),
 ('can', 'O'),
 ('delete', 'O'),
 ('this', 'O'),
 ('module', 'O'),
 ('how', 'O'),
 ('can', 'O'),
 ('I', 'O'),
 ('change', 'O'),
 ('this', 'O'),
 ('car', 'O'),
 ('I', 'O'),
 ('can', 'O'),
 ('delete', 'action'),
 ('delete', 'O'),
 ('this', 'O'),
 ('module', 'O')]
```

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385308/how-to-compare-list-values-with-dictionary-keys-and-make-a-new-dictionary-of-it) , but unable to modify it to get my expected output.

Comment: You need to add an `else` clause after `if j==k` to append `(j, 'O')` instead of appending it unconditionally.

Comment: Tried it. But I still get the same output as above.

Comment: Please show what exactly you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution utilising list comprehension:

```
docsp = [['how', 'can', 'I', 'change', 'this', 'car'], ['I', 'can', 'delete', 'this', 'module']]

ent = {'change' : 'action', 'car' : 'item', 'delete' : 'action'}

result = [[(docsp[i][j], ent.get(docsp[i][j], 'O')) for j in range(len(docsp[i]))] \
                                                    for i in range(len(docsp))]

# [[('how', 'O'),
#   ('can', 'O'),
#   ('I', 'O'),
#   ('change', 'action'),
#   ('this', 'O'),
#   ('car', 'item')],
#  [('I', 'O'),
#   ('can', 'O'),
#   ('delete', 'action'),
#   ('this', 'O'),
#   ('module', 'O')]]
```

Comment: I'm getting the below output using your approach:  [[(('how', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('can', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('I', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('change', 'action'), 'O'),
  (('this', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('car', 'item'), 'O')],
 [(('I', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('can', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('delete', 'action'), 'O'),
  (('this', 'O'), 'O'),
  (('module', 'O'), 'O')]]

Comment: it works for me. i've updated my answer with inputs as you provided.