# How do i compare items in a python LIST to DICTIONARY keys and then construct a dictionary with all elements of the LIST

Tags: python

I have a python List `a=[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

and a python dictionary `b={1: 'Poor', 2: 'Average', 3: 'Excellent'}`

and i need to find a way of comparing the list items to the dictionary keys so that in the end i have

`{2: 'Average', 1: 'Poor', 1: 'Poor' ,1:'Poor , 1:'Poor'}`

I have tried this comprehension `n = {k: z[k] for k in w if k in z}` [How to compare list values with dictionary keys and make a new dictionary of it using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385308/how-to-compare-list-values-with-dictionary-keys-and-make-a-new-dictionary-of-it) but it gives me the following output below which is not what i want [I know its because of the **in** keyword ]

`{2: 'Average', 1: 'Poor'}`

How do i make it return a dictionary like this 
`{2: 'Average', 1: 'Poor', 1: 'Poor' ,1:'Poor , 1:'Poor'}` where every element in the list is matched against the dictionary keys.

Comment: A dict can't ever have two of the same key.

Comment: You cant create a dict with repeated keys, the key value will be replaced

Comment: Python dicts don't support duplicate keys. This is the reason for the output you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a dictionary with multiple values for the same key.  A better way to represent this might be to construct a list of tuples:

```
[(score, b[score]) for score in a]
```